# Ajax Load a html file and then add a value

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Hello I have a file here called personal.html:

```
<form id="form_personal">
    <div class="row" style="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <label class="">Username:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="us"/>
            </div>

            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="success button">Submit</button>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </form>
```

As you can see from the above code, I have an id called "us". So here is what I am trying to achieve via ajax but it does not work, my

```
<div class="atest"></div>
```

is actually in a file called profile.html. So I am including personal.html via AJAX load into profile.html.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'some params, ignore this',
    dataType: 'ignore this',
    success: function(r)
    {
        $('.atest').load('personal.html');


    }
}).done(append);

function append()
{
    // alert();
    $('#us').val('test');
}
```

I am trying to put in the value of "test" into my

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="us"/>
```

which is in the personal.html file, How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait until personal.html loads completely,for that you should use complete call back of JQuery `load` method like this:

```
$('.atest').load('personal.html', function() {
    //this will run after personal.html has loaded.
    //Do your stuff here
});
```